# Using a between predicate in CASE expression

Tags: sql, postgresql, case

I want to update `target_column` based on what time `column1` has. I can do it using this:

```
update table set target_column = case 
when (column1 between now() and now() - interval '1 year') then 1.0
when (column1 between now() - interval '1 year' and now() - interval '2 years') then 2.0 
else 3.0 end;
```

But I can't do it in this way:

```
update table set target_column = case column1 
when (between now() and now() - interval '1 year') then 1.0
when (between now() - interval '1 year' and now() - interval '2 years') then 2.0 
else 3.0 end;
```

Output:

> ERROR:  syntax error at or near "now"

How can I do this? And will this lead to better performance?

Comment: Your 2nd way is simply wrong syntax. I expect you do not want to repeat `column1`? But I think there is no simple way. Query 1 is the right one.

Comment: What you want to is not possible as the syntax for the between statement requires an expression to test as it's first parameter: test_expression [ NOT ] BETWEEN begin_expression AND end_expression

Comment: @S-Man thanks, guys. I know that this is not valid syntaxis, but I thought that I can do it in this way.

Comment: Between _predicate_ in case _expression_.

Comment: "*I know that this is not valid syntaxis, but I thought that I can do it in this way*" is a contradiction. If you **know** it's not valid, then why do you think you can do it that way?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I thought that I can use another syntaxis, to achieve more performance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[As documented in the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-conditional.html#FUNCTIONS-CASE) the "simple" case expression (not "statement") in the form `case some_thing when ...` **only** allows equality conditions where the column (actually an expression) is compared with a constant value using the `=` operator.

So the following:

```
case some_column 
   when 1 then 'one'
   when 2 then 'two'
   else 'Something else'
end
```

is equivalent to:

```
case 
   when some_column = 1 then 'one'
   when some_column = 2 then 'two'
   else 'Something else'
end
```

The "simple" expression (`case some_column when ...`)  does not support anything else.

If you want to use a `between` condition you can't use it.

---

The performance of both versions should be identical. At least it will be negligible compared to the work that needs to be done to update the rows in the table and write those changes to disk.

Answer (score 1):

Your second example is a syntax error in SQL. The first example is the correct query. There is no performance penalty for using CASE this way, that’s just how you write it in SQL.